# Orchestrating Gradle build invocations with custom tasks

Tags: groovy, gradle

I’m trying to define two new Gradle tasks, `buildAll` and `pubLocal`, to run other tasks in a specific order.

When `gradle buildAll` is invoked, I want Gradle to do the same thing as if I had executed `gradle clean build writePom` (see below for `writePom`).

When `gradle pubLocal` is executed, I want Gradle to do the same thing as if `gradle buildAll install` had been executed.

Here’s my best attempt thus far:

```
// build.gradle
task writePom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'mygroup'
            artifactId 'mylib'
            version version

            inceptionYear '2015'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'Blah'
                    url 'blah'
                    distribution 'blah'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
}

task buildAll(dependsOn: clean, build, writePom)

task pubLocal(dependsOn: buildAll, install)
```

When I run `gradle buildAll` on this, I get:

```
myuser@mymachine:~/tmp/myapp$./gradlew buildAll
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Build file '/Users/myuser/tmp/myapp/build.gradle' line: 67

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myapp'.

> Could not find method buildAll() for arguments [{dependsOn=task ':clean'}, task ':build', task ':writePom'] on root project 'myapp'.
```

Any ideas as to where I’m going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a left-over from copy-pasting, but your strings are not quoted consistently using standard single- or double-quotes. Example:

```
    }.writeTo(“build/libs/pom.xml")
```

does not quote the string properly, as it opens with the `“` character instead of `"`. Same with the single-quotes above it.

You can see from the way your code is highlighted, that everything in red is interpreted as a string. If this is the case in your actual code, the `buildAll` and `pubLocal` tasks will not be recognized, as they are part of a string rather than code.

**UPDATE:**

Since the above answer is irrelevant now, here is another possibility. The error message shows that only the `"clean"` task is listed in the dependsOn parameter. The `buildAll` task dependencies should be declared like this:

```
task buildAll(dependsOn: [clean, build, writePom])
```

Similar with the `pubLocal` task.

Comment: Thanks @thecodesmith_ (+1) **yes** this was copy-paste related. I have edited my original code to show that I am in fact quoting things right, and I assure you this happens in my actual `build.gradle` which has correct quotes. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Gradle 2.4. The following file includes the Maven plugin, uses a list `[]` in the `dependsOn`, and ensures that `clean` must be executed before `build`:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

task writePom << {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'mygroup'
            artifactId 'mylib'
            version version

            inceptionYear '2015'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'Blah'
                    url 'blah'
                    distribution 'blah'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("build/libs/pom.xml")
    println "TRACER writePom"
}

task clean << { println "TRACER clean" }
task build << { println "TRACER build" }
build.mustRunAfter clean

task install << { println "TRACER install" }

task buildAll(dependsOn: [clean, build, writePom])

task pubLocal(dependsOn: [buildAll, install])
```

I get this output (minus Gradle 3 warnings):

```
bash-3.2$ gradle buildAll 
:clean
TRACER clean
:build
TRACER build
:writePom
TRACER writePom
:buildAll

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

and this:

```
bash-3.2$ gradle pubLocal
:clean
TRACER clean
:build
TRACER build
:writePom
TRACER writePom
:buildAll
:install
TRACER install
:pubLocal

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```